# How directly input and get parameter from url?

Tags: php, regex

Let say my code file is code.php and I can access it by :

```
localhost/test/code.php
```

Now I want if I enter address bar:

```
localhost/test/code.php?someparameter
```

it will automatically

```
overwrite "someparameter" string to a dummyfile.txt.
```

Is it possible to do it that way ?

I know we can use :

```
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

to get URI but how could we add the param directly to the url and it still go to the same code file and process ???
I dont want to use java script here coz my server only support php.

Comment: thanks, but its not really duplicate. How to process the thing just by entering on url, not action on webpage. I think "@Request.QueryString" might have something to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look further in writing your parameter, but it is possible to catch whether your "parameter" is set,

```
if (isset($_GET['parameter'])) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Comment: how could we just type on url, press enter, then in the code it could know variable is set and assign param value to that variable ?

Comment: Ok, I got the answer for my question. Well it quite simple when u know it : if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
  // do your thing
  file_put_contents('dummyfile.txt',$_GET['param']);
} //and at the link, just type: localhost/test/code.php?param=value

Comment: You got it! Cheers. It was unclear whether you would add a value to the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_GET["parater_name"] to get the parameter from url. And you can use $_POST for parameters in post request. $_REQUEST for get,post and session parameters.

Comment: Its quite hard for me to imagine the solution. Do I need to declare a variable in the code, then use get to get the value then post again the value ? What I mean here is ust enter the url and it will appear the param in the text file, no need andy action on the webpage.